# Transformation from Normal to LogNormal in R

Tags: r, normal-distribution, lognormal-distribution

I need to generate random numbers from LogNormal distribution by using transformation with Normal. Although I tried some way, it didn't work. How can I make it ?

Comment: What did you try?  (Consider the third sentence [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution))

Comment: How do you define (a) logNormal distribution (b) transformation (c) generation?

Answer (score 4):

You can generate random numbers from LogNorm distribution using rlnorm

```
#rlnorm(n, meanlog = 0, sdlog = 1)
X <- rlnorm(1000, 0 ,1)
hist(X) #log-norm
hist(log(X)) # norm
```

If the random variable $X$ is log-normally distributed, then $Y = \ln(X)$ has a normal distribution. Likewise, if $Y$ has a normal distribution, then $X = \exp(Y)$ has a log-normal distribution.

```
Y <- rnorm(1000,0,1)
X <- exp(Y)
hist(Y)
hist(X)
```

Comment: I have tried that way but my instructer said that this way is not enough, you need to chage something on mean and sd

Comment: Could you be more specific? The lognormal distribution has two parameters $\mu$ - location and $\sigma$ - scale. In my example I assumed the simplest approach with $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma = 1$.

If you want to have $\mu = m$ and $\sigma = s$ then just put

    `X <- m + s*exp(Y)`